# Google drive API from iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I am accessing google drive API  from ios application but getting this error message :

> please copy the code switch to your application and paste it there

[image]

Comment: It seems like some part of authorization, to enable your app to access the resources on your drive. Wasn't there anything about it in the documentation?

Comment: Yes I saw so many help from Google documentation and people question  also but nothing helpful I found. I am accessing my drive and storing file and downloading it. All work completed .  Just sometime when I press allow on permission it stuck on this screen which I have attach above. I dont know where to paste this code.